# How to copy all log files from a particular date to the current date?

Tags: files, log, find, logs

I want to copy the log files from a particular date, say Nov 18, to the current date. How can I do that?

Comment: school task? `man find` and `man xargs` will give you a lot of options, either with find alone, or in combination with xargs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `find` command:

```bash
find /path/to/logs/dir -type f -newermt '2022-11-18' -exec cp {} /path/to/copy/dir \;
```

- Replace `/path/to/logs/dir` and `/path/to/copy/dir` with the paths to the directory where your logs are and the directory you want to copy the logs to, respectively.
- `-type f` is used to search for files only.
- `-newermt '2022-11-18'` is used to find files that were last modified (this is the `mt` part of `-newermt`) after November 18 2022. Time formats are interpreted similarly to `date`'s `-d` option, so you can use `-newermt 'November 18 2022'` or any format that `date -d` can handle. See [`man date`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/date.1.html) for more.
- `-exec cp {} /path/to/copy/dir` is used to copy each found file (`{}`) to `/path/to/copy/dir`.

Note that `find` looks for files recursively, so it will also look for files that satisfy the required criteria inside directories in `/path/to/logs/dir` too. If you don't want to look recursively for the files, add the `-maxdepth 1` option right before `-type f`.

For more details see [`man find`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/find.1.html).